# "Warning" window after launching computer (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: gnome, python, 21.10

This warning window keeps popping up since I've updated to Ubuntu 21.04 and 21.10. How do I get that solved?

[image]

Comment: This is quite surely a bug or some old software (seems to be "Dell Linux Assistant" <-- ). `isAlive()` was renamed to `is_alive()` in `python` 3.9.

Comment: Did you use preinstalled Ubuntu from Dell?

Comment: @pLumo Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was installed when I bought it. Then I upgraded to 20.04 LTS, and now to 21.10

Comment: There wasn't such a problem with 20.04

Comment: sure, because 20.04 used python 3.8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Error is, that `Thread.isAlive()` is not known by your `python` version, which has changed from `3.8` to `3.9` due to the upgrade. In 3.9, the attribute has been renamed to `is_alive()`.

Seems you have a preinstalled Ubuntu from Dell, that has some software installed ("Dell Linux Assistant") that is not compatible with `python 3.9`.

You should either

- ask the Dell support if they have a fix.
- or simply try to get rid of that software, e.g.:

  ```
  sudo apt remove dell-recovery dell-linux-assistant
  ```
- or (what I'd recommend) reinstall a clean Ubuntu without Dell bloatware.

Comment: If you have asked dell or found a way to remove the software, it would be cool, if you could share your knowledge. I can also add this to my answer if it is okay for you.

Comment: thanks, I've purged dell-recovery and dell-linux-assistant and now it's solved

Comment: Dell preinstalled systems - as far as I recall - use official Dell repositories because they do things slightly different (like disabling the Windows key).  By switching to official Ubuntu you get things like this.